# Как сделать portable версию проекта релизного .exe и особенности запуска проектов .Net 5.0 и выше

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

делаю прогрмму синхронизации файлов
Начал с .Net 4.7, но перешел на .Net 5.0, т.к.в старом фреймворке не понравился вид окна FolderBrowserDialog -  окно проводника очень уж урезанно...

.net 4.7:

[image: старый фрейм]

.net 5.0:

[image: новый фрейм]

Но версии .Net свыше 4.8 в windows нативно [не поддерживаются](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed), значит придется устанавливать фреймворк вручную, точнее приложение само фреймворк-то закачает, а пользователю придется - таки при первом запуске приложения подтвердить установку фреймворка даже для портабл версии приложения.

да и на серваке не разрешена установка программ, запуск - да, установка - нет.
Переписывать на .Net 4.7 не хочу, в проекте уже много сделано. Хочу хочу, чтоб экзешник просто запускался по клику, без установок фреймворков и т.п.

Есть же для .net 7 какая-то реализация приложений через wpf но он сильно отичается от win forms. Если переписывать - лучше на wpf или на 4.7?

Как лучше поступить?

Comment: self-contained вам в помощь. `лучше на wpf или на 4.7` - WPF это аналог WinForms, он также есть и на .NET Framework и на .NET. Если не устраивает WinForms в качестве дизайна, то советую WPF. Ну и да, всегда советую последнюю версию языка и .NET.

Comment: Конечно же лучше использовать .NET 7, чем устаревший Framework 4.x. Причин много, от фичей до производительности или поддержки высоких DPI.

Comment: [Deployment models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/). Смотрите Self-contained, Single file deployment, ReadyToRun, Native AOT. Выбор богатый! Конечно же, используйте .NET 7. ЗЫ: язык документации переключается в левом нижнем углу.